# Connecting DataGrip to Hadoop (Cloudera 6) Impala through ODBC

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, impala, datagrip

could anyone help me set up a connection in DataGrip to Hadoop Impala? I know DataGrip doesn't directly support ODBC but perhaps a workaround or just something I've missed googling - JDBC?

Using DataGrip 2021.3.1

Here's my DSN-less connection string:

```
Driver=Cloudera ODBC Driver for Impala;Host=ap-cdpdn10p.oneadr.net;Port=21050;AuthMech=1;KrbRealm=ONEADR.NET;KrbFQDN=impala.cdpoe.prod.oneadr.net;KrbServiceName=impala;SSL=1;UseSystemTrustStore=1;ServicePrincipalCanonicalization=0;AllowSelfSignedServerCert=1
```

Answer (score 1):

First, please read [this article](https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_jdbc.html)

In DataGrip there is Hive driver embedded, according to the article it should work. If it does not, you can [try this one from Cloudera](https://www.cloudera.com/downloads/connectors/impala/jdbc/2-6-15.html), for example.

Comment: Overall good advice. Although I've no idea how to set up it through Kerberos as well.

Comment: @HappyCanine, do you need to set up Hive connection using Kerberos? In case I'm right, read the article [Setting Up a Hive Connection with Kerberos using Apache JDBC Drivers](https://querysurge.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001218863-Setting-Up-a-Hive-Connection-with-Kerberos-using-Apache-JDBC-Drivers-Windows-)